# I'am unable to Select only one Radio Button from this Context API list so that I can do more actions on that specific id

Tags: reactjs

I'am unable to Select only one Radio Button from this Context API list so that I can do more actions on that specific id.I want to change the name of the selected radio button as I want after selecting specific id.

```
import React from 'react'
import './Boxes.css'

export default class Boxes extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            users: [],
            selectedID: ''
        }

        this.changeSelectedId = (e, id) => {
            if (e.target.checked == true) {
                this.setState({ selectedID: id })
                console.log(this.state.users)
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https:jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                this.setState({ users: response.data })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error .....')
            })
    }
    render() {
        const { users, selectedID } = this.state
        const selectedRadio = selectedID == users.id
        return (
               <>
               {users.map((item, index) =>
                    <div className='boxes' key={index}>{<h4>Name:- {item.name}</h4>}
                    <input type='radio' names='Userradio' checked={selectedRadio} 
                     onChange={(e) => { this.changeSelectedId(e, users.id) }} />
               </div>)}
            </>
        )
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
export const Boxes = ({}) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState('');

  const changeSelectedId = (e, id) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setSelectedId(id)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https:jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setUsers(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error .....')
      })
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {users.map((item, index) => (
         <div className='boxes' key={index}>
          <h4>Name:- {item.name}</h4>
          <input 
            type='radio' 
            names='Userradio' 
            checked={item.id === selectedId} 
            onChange={(e) => changeSelectedId(e, item.id)} 
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```